# How $maxFileAge from upload.php works

Tags: php, plupload

I'm currently using [plupload](http://plupload.com) API and there is upload.php as their sample. There is a $maxFileAge variable in upload.php and it was used in a IF statement and said that will remove old temp files. I want to know how can i check if this works and so on. 
here is the variable:

```
$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds
```

and somewhere down there is the if statement:

```
// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir) {
    if (!is_dir($targetDir) || !$dir = opendir($targetDir)) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }

    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

        // If temp file is current file proceed to the next
        if ($tmpfilePath == "{$filePath}.part") {
            continue;
        }

        // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
        if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) || (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge)) {
            @unlink($tmpfilePath);
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```

Comment: It looks like it will work. Change it to `$maxFileAge = 5 * 60;`, upload some files, wait like 10 minutes, upload one file, check if old uploaded files are still inside directory.

Comment: i tried what you said and nothing happened. i also tried $maxFileAge = 1 * 60; and don't work also.

Comment: Is `$cleanupTargetDir` set to true? Use `die(var_dump($cleanupTargetDir));` in line just after `// Remove old temp files` and upload file.

Comment: yes it is set to true. I used echo in all variables declared and all was good.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at beginning of file. And check permissions to directory `$targetDir`. What OS do you have?

Comment: I know now the answer, this really works. It will delete the file if it exceeds in $maxfileAge value and it was done every time it triggers the button. Upload.php is an ajax so if you start to upload image again it will do if statements and it will delete the files. thank you piotrekkr. this really helps me a lot.

Comment: Thats why I told you to set time to 5 minutes, upload few files, wait 10 minutes, upload something again and check if old files are still there. If old files are deleted then script works as expected.

Comment: yeah i just realized this when i read again your comment. And again thank you for helping me.